# How to set string array with a product to an array with the price?

Tags: java, arrays

The problem is "Write a program in a class SandwichCounter that computes
the cost of sandwiches sold at a food stand. Three kinds
of sandwiches —cheese steak, chicken, and salad— are cost,
respectively, $8.5, $7.5, and $7.0 per sandwich. Create an 
array of strings that holds the names of these sandwiches. 
Create another array that holds the cost of each corresponding 
sandwich. Your program should read the name of a sandwich and 
the quantity desired by a customer. Locate the sandwich in the
name array and use that index to find the cost per purchase in
the cost array. Compute and print the total cost of the sale" I figured I should just make the two arrays and set them equal to each other so salad = 7.0 but I cant figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: You are not to set the arrays equal to each other but find the index of the chosen sandwich and then use that index (int) to get the price from the other array. I assume that this is homework and you have a textbook or other course material that explains how to loop over an array and how to compare two strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your class would be similar to the following:

```
public class SandwichCounter {
    private String[] sandwiches;
    private double[] prices;

    public void SandwichCounter() {
        sandwiches = {"Cheese Steak", "Chicken", "Salad"};
        prices = {8.50, 7.50, 7.00};
    }

    public void placeOrder(String sandwichName, int quantity) {
        // Boolean variable which will determine if the sandwich name is in our array (list of sandwiches).
        boolean orderPlaced = false;

        // Loop through the names of the sandwiches.
        for (int i = 0; i < sandwiches.length; i++) {
            // If the name is in the array
            if (sandwiches[i].equals(sandwichName)) {
                // Compute the cost of the sandwich.
                double cost = prices[i] * quantity;

                // Print the cost of the sandwich(es) ordered.
                System.out.println("The cost of " + quantity + " " + sandwichName + " sandwich(es) is: $" + cost + ".");

                orderPlaced = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // The name of the sandwich is not in the array.
        if (orderPlaced == false) {
            System.out.println("We have no sandwich by the name " + sandwichName + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, don't answer questions which do not show any effort.